# UI-Router and optional parametr in subroute without reloading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have site with two columns. There is a list of conversations on the left and conversation detail on the right and I would like to have routes in **UI-Router** like this:

```
/messages - initial route will redirect to first conversation
/messages/:id - this will load conversation list and requested detail
```

I tried to make separated states in UI-router but it reloads entire view and controller - I would like to just get new `$stateChange` event and don't reload controller..

My actual semi-working solution is this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('messages', {
        url: '/messages',
        templateUrl: 'templates/messages/list.html',
        controller: 'MessagesCtrl'
    })
    .state('messages.root', {
        url: '/:id'
    })
```

Which does not reload entire controller when I'm changing parameter in URL, but when I load for example this url *`/messages/556d6f8e64303702b1000000`* I will not get and ID in **`$stateParams.id`** variable..

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R5HutoQ67CuPOeTQEMS8?p=preview)

The point is - parameter is declared on child state, so only child state controller can access it

Child state has controller:

```
.state('messages', {
    url: '/messages',
    templateUrl: 'templates/messages/list.html',
    controller: 'MessagesCtrl'
})
.state('messages.root', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    controller: 'ChildCtrl',
})
```

Child controller has access to these params defined for it:

```
.controller('MessagesCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  console.log("was initated");
}])
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams) { 
  console.log("child was initated");
  console.log($stateParams.id);
}])
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R5HutoQ67CuPOeTQEMS8?p=preview)

In case we would like to track what is the current active link - and track it in a parent, while active is child - we have built in support.

#### [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active)

There is [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xbCLf25a9qDaYGLUpFsF?p=preview)

So this could be our parent template 'templates/messages/list.html' content:

```
...
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="messages.root({id:1})">
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="messages.root({id:'556d6f8e64303702b1000000'})">
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="messages.root({id:'556d6f8e64303702b1bbbbbb'})">
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="messages.root({id:'556d6f8e64303702b1xxxxxx'})">
```

There are other ways like using [**`$state.includes(stateOrName, params, options)`**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

> A method to determine if the current active state is equal to or is the child of the state stateName. If any params are passed then they will be tested for a match as well. Not all the parameters need to be passed, just the ones you'd like to test for equality.

Comment: So maybe is there any other way, how to make optional parameter without need of reloading MessagesCtrl? In my case MessagesCtrl is just loading conversation list and conversation detail which is then shown in directive..

Comment: Well, you can always (as my plunker does) paste the $stateParams into $rootScope... and observe it. But I am working with UI-Router for a while, and must say, that I really use params at state level where they are defined... Any other approach seems to me a bit "breaking architecture"... but ...

Comment: One reason I wanted to be able to read $stateParams.id value in MessageCtrl is, that I'm highlighting currently opened conversation.. How would you do this if you can access detail ID only in sub controller?

Comment: Extended the answer with more details, included updated plunker, provided more links to resources.. hope, you have some ideas now ;)

Comment: If that helped anyhow... that is really great. Enjoy amazing UI-Router, Honzo ;) ;)